# Generating edit pages with Subcommander

Tags: subsonic

Has anyone used Subcommander to generate views or edit aspx pages in webforms projects.
If so any tips/help advice or alternatives would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I was under the impression that SubCommander is simply for using SubSonic under a command prompt? I don't think it was ever designed to start generating views / edit pages for you.

There are however (if you're referring to SubSonic 2) scaffolds which will certainly assist with what you're trying to achieve.

From within your ASP.NET html page paste the following code for each object / table you wish to scaffold:

```
<subsonic:Scaffold ID="Scaffold1" runat="server" TableName="YOURTABLENAMEGOESHERE">
</subsonic:Scaffold>
```

Comment: Yeah SubCommander is used for that in the context of Subsonic but I started to have a look at the code and its uses templates to do code generation.  I've heard that some folks modified it for uses as a code generation system and was wondering if anyone had done it and could give me a head start.

Comment: I may end up using T4 but thought this would be cool for .net 2 project.  (I don't think T4 works for .net 2 stuff)

Comment: The subsonic templates are just to create the .cs files and not the .aspx files. 

Also t4 templates are more to do with Visual Studio version than .Net version. So yes you can use tt in .NET 2.0